# Access Denied Java FileWriter / FileInputStream

Tags: java

My program downloads a websites source code, modifies it, creates the file, and then reuploads it through the FTP.  However, I receive the following error when trying to open the created file:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: misc.html (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Manipulator.uploadSource(Manipulator.java:63)
at Start.addPicture(Start.java:130)
at Start$2.actionPerformed(Start.java:83)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When I navigate to the folder directory and attempt to open "misc.html" with Notepad I receive Access is Denied.  My code is fairly simple:

```
File f = new File(page.sourceFileName);
    try {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(f);
        out.write(page.source);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } InputStream  input = new FileInputStream(f);
```

This is the vital excerpt from my program.  I have copied this into a different test program and it works fine, I create a misc.html file and reopen it with both FileInputStream and manually.

I would be worried about Administrator rights but the Test program works fine when I run it RIGHT after the problem program.  I also have checked if the file exists and is a file with File methods and it is as well.  Is this a result of me not closing a previous Input/Output properly?  I've tried to check everything and I am fairly positive I close all streams as soon as they finish...

Help! :)

UPDATE:

If I comment out the FileInputStream code and just leave the FileWriter the File still is Access Denied.  If I remove the FileWriter code, no File is made (so it's certainly not overwriting anything).  The FileWriter code is the first time the file is made and no exception is thrown - but I still cannot manually open the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have sufficient permissions to read that file, then the thing I can notice is that you are not using streams properly:

```
out.write(page.source); // if this throws an exception
out.close(); //this is not called, and the file remains open
```

You must close the streams in a `finally` block.

```
FileWriter fw = null;
try {
   fw = new FileWriter(f);
   fw.write(page.source);
} catch (IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace(); //consider a logger
} finally {
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(fw);
}
```

The same goes for the `InputStream`s

Now, the `IOUtils.closeQuietly(fw)` is a bit controversial, since it will not report an exception that happens during the closing of a file. And it is from apache commons-io (external dependency). You can replace it with another `try-catch` inside the `finally` and then a `null` check, before calling `close()`. Luckily this will be a lot easier in Java 7.

Comment: If you _do_ have rights to read the file, that's the thing I can spot. Fix your stream handling and try again.

Comment: I still receive the same stack trace.  The FileWriter seems to write fine, but somehow it creates "misc.html" in a way that FileInputStream cannot open it.  The catch for FileInputStream grabs the error and does not need to close it (null check) because its instantiation failed.

Comment: I've fixed my error catching for everything in my program but, as far as I can see, the only exception thrown is for FileInputStream.  I pasted a reply to a comment below where the absolute path is printed in error.  If it is a permission issue, would it be because of my path location>

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error seems to happen when trying to work on a directory. Sure you don't?

Make some extra log output what you open and close, and return here....

Comment: Is file? true Is Writeable? true Is Readable? true Is Executable? true Absolute Path: C:\Users\Matt\workspace\PictureUploader\misc.html

Answer (score 0):

Does your program run in as an Applet or WebStart application? If so, it is likely that the JVM sandbox is preventing your (untrusted) code from accessing the local filesystem.

Comment: I'm not well versed with Java and Eclipse but when I run my program I always use Application as opposed to Applet.